# problem with format date in react component

Tags: reactjs, date, redux

Format the date in react component. I tried to call `toLocaleDateString`, and other options, all to no avail. Either I didn’t receive any changes, either the error '.... is not a function'

The date component comes in this format:

> 2018-10-07T06:39:55.578686Z

Comment: Please describe the issue in detail with detailed error message and also please share the code which is causing the error

Comment: Library like moment or luxon are very efficient for this type of problematic. Please share code if you want a precise answer.

Comment: DO NOT use moment.js if you are trying to solve single problem. Use it only if you need it in your project globaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Date()` to do this. You won't need `moment()` for this.

```js
let d = "2018-10-07T06:39:55.578686Z"
let date = new Date(d);
let formattedDate = date.toDateString() //Or any other methods that date supports
console.log(formattedDate);
```